# How to create multiple element by js

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to freeze column in my table when i scroll the table in right.
I did it statically using js, but in this case would there be a way to indicate the number of columns to get the following style ?

My js code looks that:

```
var styles =`
 table:first-of-type thead tr th:first-child{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
 background-color:white;
color:crimson;
      left: 0px;
   z-index: 3;
  
}

table:first-of-type tbody tr td:first-child{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: crimson;

    left: 0px;
color:black;
   z-index: 1;
  
  
}
table:first-of-type thead tr th:nth-child(2){
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    color: black;
          left: 30px;
      z-index: 3;
}

table:first-of-type tbody tr td:nth-child(2){
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: black;
      left: 30px;    
   z-index: 1;
}
table:first-of-type thead tr th:nth-child(3){
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    color: black;
          left: 138px;
      z-index: 3;
}

table:first-of-type tbody tr td:nth-child(3){
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: black;
      left: 138px;    
   z-index: 1;
}
`;
var styleSheet = document.createElement("style")
styleSheet.innerText = styles
document.head.appendChild(styleSheet)
```

In this case, I would have to add nth-child each time, but would it be possible to create this with a js function?

Comment: _"but would it be possible to create this with a js function?"_ - sure it would, all you have there is a string value, which can easily be assembled "dynamically".

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/LifeCSS) here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map you left values in an array:

```js
const style = 
` table:first-of-type thead tr th:first-child{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
 background-color:white;
color:crimson;
      left: 0px;
   z-index: 3;
  
}

table:first-of-type tbody tr td:first-child{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: crimson;

    left: 0px;
color:black;
   z-index: 1;
  
  
}`

 + [30, 138].map((left, idx) => 

`
table:first-of-type thead tr th:nth-child(${idx+2}){
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    color: black;
          left: 30px;
      z-index: 3;
}

table:first-of-type tbody tr td:nth-child(${idx+2}){
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: black;
      left: ${left}px;    
   z-index: 1;
}
`);

$('pre').text(style);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```